# What is the instruction of checking which version of cuda and cudnn the tensorflow is running on?

Tags: tensorflow

What is the instruction of checking which version of cuda and cudnn the tensorflow is running on?
like the tensorflow version could be checked by the instruction tf.version .
I want to check my tensorflow 1.4 running on the 8.0 cuda and 6.0 cudnn, not running on the 9.0 cuda and 7.0 cudnn.

Comment: There is an open issue for this - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4003 and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10827